# How to prevent 'dict object' has no attribute for task options

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Given the following configuration

```
---
my_items:
  my_item:
    folder: '/tmp'
```

And task that uses custom `restore_info`

```
- name: Restore info
  restore_info:
    folder: '{{ my_items[item]["folder"] }}'   
  with_items: '{{ my_items }}'
```

The "folder attribute" is optional. So it could be that the configuration only contains

```
---
my_items:
  my_item:
```

The problem is that provision will fail if "folder" is not present.  To workaround this issue

```
- name: Restore info
  restore_info:
    folder: '{{ my_items[item]["folder"] if my_items[item]["folder"] is not defined }}'   
  with_items: '{{ my_items }}'
```

But this also makes the task fail if folder

Is there a way to conditionally add arguments to a task, so that the task won't fail if the "folder" attribute is not present?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `default(omit)`

```
- name: Restore info
  restore_info:
    folder: '{{ my_items[item]["folder"] | default(omit) }}'   
  with_items: '{{ my_items }}'
```